# Thermo-electric current in the p-type semiconductor

Tags: semiconductor-physics, thermoelectricity

I came across this picture :
[image]

Source:[thermo-electric generators](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Thermoelectric_Generator_Diagram.svg)

Basically, within the p-type semiconductor, I don't know how holes move from the hot side to the cold one. How does this happen?  If this case is right, doesn't that mean that the valence electrons in the p-type move from the cold region to hot one!? Which in not intuitive for me!
I just want a clarification for this point?

Comment: To what extent does it depend on the material?

Comment: Note that when dealing with semiconductors you really need to think of electrons and holes (not as valence electrons!) on the same footing. So, if you understand how the electrons do what they do, what is the issue with the holes doing the same thing for the same reason?